# SQLAlchemy: Query max amount per year

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model, `Photo` with a date column. I am making a photo gallery that has an overview view that shows a maximum of 5 photos for each year that there are photos.

Currently I have this query, and have it loop through a manually-made list of the years. 
 (i.e. `for year in range(2000, 2016):`)

```
Photo.query \
.filter(extract('year', Photo.date)==year) \
.order_by(Photo.date) \
.limit(5) \
.all()
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this (instead of 15 queries)? Also, but less important, is there a way the years can be sorted based off what years photos exist for (as an alternative to using a hard-coded list)?

UPDATE: I am using sqlite3

Comment: the right query will depend somewhat on the database you're using, can you include that in your question?

Comment: I think this should be accomplished `group_by()`  but cannot point to a good example http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.group_by

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thank you, that looks very promising. It looks like I can group by year via `.group_by(sqla.func.year(Photo.date))`. I will play around with this and see if this is what I need.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa after reading around for some bit, it seems `group_by()` will give me years (helpful for my second question). Can I use it to get the actual models in those years as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one assumption that the `date` is unique, the query below should work for `sqlite`:

```
# define aliases as we will need to join the table on itself
p1 = Photo
p2 = db.aliased(Photo, name='p2')

q = (
    p1.query
    # join *Photo* on itself and count the *rank* of current photo by counting the photos with date before it in the same year
    .join(p2, sa.and_(
        sa.func.extract("year", p1.date) == sa.func.extract("year", p2.date),
        p1.date >= p2.date,
    ))
    .group_by(p1.id)
    .having(sa.func.count() <= 5)
    .order_by(p1.date)  # This will automatically order by year and rank
)
```

If `date` is not unique, but *almost* unique, there result will not always be 5 rows, but can be more or less. If these really are `date` values (without time component), let me know - it should be easy to get a more robust solution.